# what will happen to FILE stream buffer when socket connection disconnect abnormally?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

my TCP server code is like this:

```
conn_fd = accept();  
stream = fdopen(conn_fd...);  
//...   
fp = fopen(path, "r");   
while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    fputc(c, stream);
```

---

if socket disconnect for some reason(ethernet line unpluged), will fputc function block the calling process? what will happen to stream buffer?
if fputc function blocking, could I set SO_SNDTIMEO to solve the problem?

thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

On connection termination all read/write functions will return an error (reading starts to fail only after reading out incoming buffer). Check errno if you want to be sure why no more data can be read/written.

Comment: Note though that connection termination may not be detected in a timely manner - if so, the `fputc()` function *can* block, once the send buffer fills up.

Comment: Indeed so, and default TCP timeouts are rather long. But such situation will only happen on network failure - when TCP termination packet can't be sent and data packages have no replies at all.

Comment: Actually by default the program will get a SIGPIPE signal and be terminated rather than seeing an error.

Comment: Is that really true? I think only stdout behave that way.